# What's the Time Complexity and total no of iterations?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

**for a=1 to m means for(a=1;a<=m;a++)**

```
for i=1 to n 
 for j=i to n
   c= c+1;
```

The total no of iterations is O(n^2)

```
i=1,j executes n times.
i=2,j executes n-1 times.
.
.
.
i=n, j executes 1 times.
```

So
Total No of iterations = n+n-1 + n-2+ ..... + 1 = Sum of n natural numbers = O(n^2)

For the Time complexity of the given algorithm, i executes n times and j executes from i to n so it will be O(n*(n-i+1)) = O(n^2). Am I correct in my answer and approach for both of the solution?

Comment: We discourage "Please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as they are unlikely to be useful to others in the future.  Our mission is to build up an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future.  Perhaps you might consider whether there is some conceptual aspect that would be relevant even to others who aren't looking the exact same snippet of code or exercise as you.

Comment: Sure, I will take care the next time that my question will be helpful to others not only me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach is correct. The idea is that the sum of the first $n$ numbers can be computed as $$\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2} = \dfrac{n^2 + n}{2} = O(n^2)$$

I would not consider the second one as complete, as since $i$ is a free variable in your complexity expression, the result does not immediately follow unless you quantify over $i$ (which would result in you obtaining the expression above).